# can't read variables out of app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

what I have in `app.config` is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
          <section name="Porject.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
     </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Porject.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="PhotoLocation" serializeAs="String">
            <value>.\photos\</value>
        </setting>
    </Porject.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>

<connectionStrings>
   <add name="****" connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=***;Password=***" />
</connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

and this is how I call the PhotoLocation:

```
  string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhotoLocation"];
```

When I make a request to get the connectionstring, there is no problem and it works fine; but when I requst the `PhotoLocation` it returns null.
Also the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count` returns 0.

Does anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply add this in your App config file

```
<appSettings>

    <add key="PhotoLocation" value=".\photos\"/>

<appSettings>
```

Comment: That is not what is being asked. AppSettings is a very rudimentary configuration section without strong typing and so on. OP has created or wants to access a [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) which requires another approach.

Answer (score 2):

[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) reads (as the name might suggest) the `AppSettings` block of your configuration.

Given you've created your own section, you want to use `var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Porject.Properties.Settings")` and read the values from that section.